# Why isn't the arrow operator in C++ just an alias of *.?

Tags: c++, operators

In c++, the * operator can be overloaded, such as with an iterator, but the arrow (->) (.*) operator does not work with classes that overload the * operator. I imagine that the preprocessor could easily replace all instances of -> with (*left).right, and that would make iterators nicer to implement. is there a practical reason for -> to be different, or is that just a peculiarity of the language/designers?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The rule that `foo->bar` equals `(*foo).bar` only holds for the builtin operators.

Unary `operator *` doesn't always have the pointer dereference semantics. I could make a library in which it means matrix transposition, zero-or-more parser matches, or pretty much anything.

It would make the language more bothersome if anything that overloads unary `operator *` would suddenly gain an `operator ->` you did not ask for, with semantics that might not make sense.

`operator ->` is separately overloadable, so if you want one, you can overload one with minimal effort.

Also note that such an overload would have some rather interesting properties, like automatically chaining `operator ->` calls until one in the chain returns a raw pointer. This is quite useful for smart pointers and other proxy types.

```
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

struct Foo
{
    boost::shared_ptr<std::string> operator -> () const
    {
        return boost::make_shared<std::string>("trololo");
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    std::cerr << foo->size() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: What does your example illustrate? Are you returning a smart pointer to a string and somehow outputting the size? I'm confused.

Comment: It illustrates the last paragraph of my answer, how using the `->` operator chains until it gets a raw pointer to something, dereferencing and accessing a member of it. If operator -> didn't chain, the example would be ill-formed as a shared_ptr is not a raw pointer.

Comment: @LarsViklund: your answer has a problem: you said "operator-> ... automatically chains operator-> calls until one in the chain returns a raw pointer". This is not correct - using `A->B` syntax chains at most 1 additional call. What the C++ -> binary syntax actually does is not call the object's `opeartor->` directly - instead it looks at the type of `A` and check if its a raw pointer. If it is then `->` derefs it and execute `B` on that, otherwise it calls the object's `operator->`, derefs the result (either using native raw pointer or another `operator->` and then executes `B` on the  result

Comment: @Guss: I cannot find any chapter and verse for your claim, nor reproduce it in a compiler. C++11 13.5.6/1 indicates that if a suitable overload exists, `x->m` shall be interpreted as `(x.operator->())->m`. If the LHS is something that has a suitable overload of `operator->` again, this process recurs until there's just the usual `(*x).m` effect of 5.2.5/2.

Answer (score 9):

"The C++ Programming Language" describes the fact that these operators are different so that they can be, but also says:

> If you provide more than one of these operators, it might be wise to provide the equivalence, just as it is wise to ensure that `++x` and `x+=1` have the same effect as `x=x+1` for a simple variable `x` of some class if ++,+=,=, and + are provided.

So it seems that the language designers provided separate overload points because you *might* want to overload them differently, rather than assuming that you *always* want them to be the same.

Answer (score 8):

As a general rule, C++ is designed to favor flexibility, so overloads of `*` and `->` are separate. Though it's fairly unusual to do so, if you want to badly enough you can write those overloads to do entirely different things (e.g., might make sense for a domain specific language implemented inside of C++).

That said, iterators *do* support either usage. On ancient implementations, you might find a library that requires `(*iter).whatever` instead of `iter->whatever`, but if so, that's a bug in the implementation, not a characteristic of the language. Given the amount of work involved in implementing all the standard containers/algorithms/iterators, it's not surprising that some early releases were somewhat incomplete, but they were never really intended to be that way.

Comment: I didn't realize standard library containers implemented ->, or that it was overloadable.

Comment: C++03 24.1/1 requires that any iterator where `(*i).m` is valid must support `i->m` with the same semantics.